# Using Esri proxy configuration

Tags: wfs

I have a requirement to access WFS services (using Esri/WfsLayer) which are hosted in remote servers and I have to use Esri provided proxy [code](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/releases) due to CORS policy issues.

My application is deployed in **domain1.com** and I am planning to deploy the proxy service in **domain2.com**.  I was trying with this approach, but couldn't achieve it using the codebase given [here(jsp)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html) . I am getting the same CORS issue with this.

Could anyone confirm if this is possible to do?

Because the proxy requests works if both application and proxy services are deployed in the same domain (I tested the same using sample application). But unfortunately I cannot deploy the proxy code in the same domain where my application is deployed.

My Proxy.config file is as follows

```
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="*"
               logFile="proxy_log.log"
               logLevel="INFO"
               mustMatch="true"> <serverUrls>    
<serverUrl url="https://xxxxxxx/arcgis/services/xxxxx/MapServer/WFSServer" matchAll="true"/>   
</serverUrls> </ProxyConfig>
```

Comment: if using .htaccess you can do two domains https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Comment: thanks for your response. actually I wanted to call the remote services from my 'domain1' via the esri java proxy deployed in 'domain2'. I hope this stackoverflow answer is for server side implementation if we are using PHP?